# There are $3$ Teachers and $6$ students ; How many ways can we seat them such that every teacher sit between $2$ students

Tags: permutations, combinations

> There  are $3$ Teachers and $6$ students ; How many ways can we seat them such that every teacher sit between $2$ students if the seating
>
> a) in a row
>
> b) a round circle

My try  for the first  part follows

Number of ways to seat teachers $3!$

Number of ways to seat students  $6!$

Answer =$3!×6!=4320$

Is my answer right ?

Comment: Not following your calculation.  First you have to set the pattern...if the teachers (and students) are indistinguishable, how many patterns are there?

Comment: What you have calculated seems to only be for one specific configuration of teachers (T) and students (S), assuming you can tell the Ts and Ss apart. You need to multiply with the number of ways of configuring T,S in a way that satisfy the requirement of Ts in between Ss.

Comment: @lulu  i think there are $3$ patterns ; first the teachers sit in the places 1 , 3, 5 or 3,5,7 or 5,7,9  , is my approach  right?

Comment: What do you think they are?

Comment: @lulu  i think there are $3$ patterns ; first the teachers sit in the places 1 , 3, 5 or 3,5,7 or 5,7,9  , is my approach  right?

Comment: Teacher can't sit in $1$ (not between two students).  There are more than $3$.  There are $3$ that contain the block $STSTSTS$ and that's not all of them.

Comment: @lulu  Can you help me with detailed answer ; this is beyond my knowledge,?

Comment: Just list the patterns.  It's not that hard.  Start with $STSTSTS$ as a base.  Now you have $2$ students left.  They can go in any of the $4$ slots between teachers (or on a side).  That will give you the linear patterns.  Then you have to look at those to decide which are equivalent on the circle.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57885/discussion-between-prayer-smith-and-lulu).

Comment: Sorry, I don't go into chat rooms, even for math.  Get the linear count done...all you have to do is place the two extra students. You can simply list them.

Comment: @lulu STSTSTSSS ; SSSTSTSTS ; STSSSTSTS , STSTSSSTS ; STSSTSST , SSTSTSTSS , STSSTSTSS; SSTSSTSTS , Are there other patterns?

Comment: Given the block $STSTSTS$ let's place the other two.  There are four cases in which they both go to the same slot.  There are $\frac {4\times 3}2=6$ ways to place them so that they go to different slots.  That's $6+4=10$.  You seem to have left off the ones where both extras go on one side.

Comment: @lulu ; OK ; there are 10 different patterns , i need you to  tell me how to calculate  the ways for one of them and i will complete!!

Comment: That part you did correctly.  That is, you correctly computed the number of ways to populate a given linear pattern.  You still have to sort out which of these are equivalent under rotation on a circle.

Comment: @lulu ; so the answer is $10× 3!×6!$

Comment: Barring blunder, yes.

Answer (score 0):

In a row: use 6! rows of students. There are 5 inserting places available for 3 teachers. This is a choice "3 out of 5" without repetitions. Teachers have 3! calling orderings and are placed from left to right. Conclusion: $6!*binomial(5,3)*3! = 43200$

Around a table: there are 6!/6=5! ways to put 6 students in a circle. There are now 6 intermediate places for inserting a teacher (these positions also form a circle, but we need no division by 6 since we have recognizable students at places). This is a choice "3 out of 6" without repetitions. Teachers have 3! calling orderings and are placed clockwise. Conclusion: 5!*binomial(6,3)*3!= 14400.